# change popover background color in bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap table and I want a call to action button at the last column which opens a popover. I've used custom class but can't change the color of the background.

Also only the first popover opens in the table. If I click on the second or third popover, it doesn't do anything.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
        <template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
          <cs-button id="callToAction" tabindex="-1">click me</cs-button>
           <b-popover
            ref="callToAction"
            target="callToAction"
            triggers="click blur"
            custom-class="my-popover-class"
          >
            <div @click="hello(data.item)">Edit Key</div>
          </b-popover>
        </template>
      </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      val: '',
      fields: [
        { key: 'name', label: 'Name', sortable: true },
        { key: 'id', label: 'Id', sortable: true },
        { key: 'action', label: '' },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Molly Holly',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
        },
        {
          name: 'John doe',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
        },
        {
          name: 'Bruce Wayne',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
        },
        {
          name: 'Mike Brown',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hello(d) {
      console.log(d);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.my-popover-class {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are some issues with your code.

First, you should define the action column in your data in order to see the `action` column in your `b-table`.

Second, for different rows, you need to declare different `id` values. With this, when you click on different buttons you are calling different popovers, however, you just define one id and one target, so it is just working for the first row and not the others.

For your `CSS` problem, I just changed the color of the popover arrow and used `!important` to overwrite the bootstrap CSS style.

I prepare one snippet to show you how your code can improve.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      val: '',
      fields: [{
          key: 'name',
          label: 'Name',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: 'id',
          label: 'Id',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: 'action',
          label: ''
        },
      ],
      items: [{
          name: 'Molly Holly',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
          action: "action-1"
        },
        {
          name: 'John doe',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
          action: "action-2"
        },
        {
          name: 'Bruce Wayne',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
          action: "action-3"
        },
        {
          name: 'Mike Brown',
          id: '89214bhkjshf',
          action: "action-4"
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hello(d) {
      console.log(d);
    },
  },
  mounted() {


  }


})
```

```css
.my-popover-class {
  background: black !important;
}

.my-popover-class .arrow::after {
  border-left-color: black !important;
}

.my-popover-class .popover-body {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div>
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
      <template v-slot:cell(action)="data">
        <b-button :id="`callToAction${data.index}`">click me</b-button>
        <b-popover :target="`callToAction${data.index}`" triggers="click blur" custom-class="my-popover-class">
          <div @click="hello(data.item)">Edit Key</div>
        </b-popover>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the popover is working for each item. The color for the background isn't changing however, even with `!important`

Comment: Where do you put your style? In `<style scoped>` or `<style>` ? You should put these styles in the later or in your `global.css`.

Comment: I put the styles in style scoped

Comment: Ok, put your styles in `global.css` or `<style>` tag without scope and it will work. It's because your scoped styles doesn't affect the `b-vue` components specially in popover case.